# Launch grunt from outside directory

Tags: javascript, terminal, gruntjs, command-line-interface

Is it possible to start a grunt task via the terminal without being in my working folder ?

I'm asking this because I'm trying to automate the grunt command, but my terminal command will be executed from my personal folder.

I tried these but without success :

```
weyland$ /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/app/js/grunt
No such file or directory


cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/app/js/ & grunt
Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set two params `--base` and `--gruntfile`

So, you can call watch task, for example:

```
grunt --base your_path --gruntfile your_app_path/GruntFile.js watch
```

If you call grunt --help:

`--base` Specify an alternate base path. By default, all file paths are relative to the Gruntfile. (grunt.file.setBase) *

`--gruntfile` Specify an alternate Gruntfile. By default, grunt looks in the current or parent directories for the nearest Gruntfile.js or Gruntfile.coffee file.

Hope it helps.

Regards.